# How to pass data to c3 graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

Here is my JS code:

```
var abc = JSON.stringify(dataObject);
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#container',
    data: {
       json: abc,
       keys: {
           x:'_id',
           value: ['a', 'b','c','d'],
       },
       axis: {
          x: {
              type: 'timeseries',
          }
      }

   }
});
```

The above code gives error:`undefined is not a function.`

However if I directly give the same data directly without storing in a variable, the code works.
Please let me know what the mistake is.

Comment: what data is comming in `dataObject`?

Comment: Do you encounter any errors in JSON.stringify(dataObject)??? Refer console

Comment: @MohitArora: [ {"_id":1404412200000,"a":6,"b":10,"c":6,"d":20},
                                {"_id":1404671400000,”a":4,”b":0,”c":4,”d":9},
                                {"_id":1405276200000,”a":30,”b":25,”c":20,”d":15}
                            ] This is data that I'm able to log into console. If I directly initialise data with this json , it works. But when I pass it into an object it doesnt.

Comment: @ManoNamo : no I dont encounter any error when i log dataObject into console

Comment: Why do you want to stringify the dataObject? I believe c3 expects json object itself. Try using dataObject directly (or) after parsing it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/8/ its working fine try to remove JSON.stringify

Comment: @MohitArora: Any help with above to print dates on x-axis? _id is a timestamp .

Comment: @zooney do you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/9/ (seems your timestamp invalid validate here http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: @MohitArora : no need to multiply by 1000 ,I gets correct date on the fiddle then . But when I use same thing in my code my 'tick' attribute is not doing anything . And I get timestamp only as output.

Comment: any error in browser console? are you passing timestamp as string? try to parse as int.

Comment: tick: {
              format: function (x) {
                                            var d = new Date(parseInt(x));
                                            var curr_day = d.getDate();
                                            var curr_month = d.getMonth();
                                            var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
                                            console.log(curr_day);
                                            return curr_day+'-'+parseInt(curr_month)+(1)+'-'+curr_year;
                                        }
                                    }

Comment: @MohitArora: console doesn't log anything and I get timestamp only as output. I guess tick is not working.

Answer (score 0):

i got the Answer , it works fine with me . Remove JSON.stringify(dataObject).

it will already Stringify by the c3.js it self

Answer (score 0):

Remove `JSON.stringify(dataObject)`.

It will already Stringify by the **c3.js** itself

Answer (score 0):

According to c3js documentation here : http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-json

You don't need to convert, You are getting undefined error because your keys are already in double quotes. Your data is already JSON, therefore you don't need to convert it, C3js automatically parse it unless there is syntax error.

If your data is valid JSON/Javascript object then C3js will parse it for you.

```
[{
    "_id": 1404412200000,
    "a": 6,
    "b": 10,
    "c": 6,
    "d": 20
}]
```

OR

```
[{
    _id: 1404412200000,
    a: 6,
    b: 10,
    c: 6,
    d: 20
}]
```

Notice the difference first one is JSON and second one is Javascript Object

Answer (score -1):

I stopped in the same error. I think stringify adds characters c3js no interpret