# Unable to display JSON data in C3 line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, c3.js

I am trying to display a line chart on my webpage but constantly getting this error:

> Uncaughterror type"cannot use in operator to search "Hits"

My JSON data:

```
[
  {"Month":"jan", "Hits":"235", "user":"17"},
  {"Month":"feb", "Hits":"1", "user":"1"}
]
```

I am loading it through parameter data.

I tried to change `c3.min.js` and `d3.v3.min.js`, but it does not work.

My code:

```
var  chart = c3.generate({
  bindto : '#chart',                      
  data: {
    json: [data],                                                                  
    keys: {                                              
      x: 'Month',
      value: ['Hits'],
    },                                
    type : 'line',
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is the code that you tried and didn't work?

Comment: Your josn format is not correct

Comment: var chart = c3.generate({ bindto : '#chart',
                                     data: {
                                          json: [data],


                                      keys: {

                                            x: 'Month',
                                            value: ['Hits'],
                                      },

                                      type : 'line',
                                  }
                              });

Comment: is it ??(json format issue)  because I tried in jsfiddle and this data worked fine and gave me a graph

Comment: @Jay your formatting isnt much better..

Comment: actually the reason why my json data looks like this is because its extacted   from a html  table

Comment: <script>
$('#convert-table').click( function() {
  var table = $('#example-table').tableToJSON(); 
  console.log(table);
  var data=(JSON.stringify(table));
});  and apprently when we use JSON.stringify(table), c3 js gets confused.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582181/how-to-pass-data-to-c3-graph... is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your x-axis as a category type else it's expecting some timestamp.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AkoyaP6618/6cLh45mx/4/

```
var data = [
  {"Month":"jan", "Hits":"235", "user":"17"},
  {"Month":"feb", "Hits":"1", "user":"1"}
]


 var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            json: data,
            keys: {
                x: 'Month', // can be used when x is specyfied as category
                value: ['Hits', 'user'],
            }
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category' //specify x as category
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: when your json data is primary the array containing your objects, did you directly referenced this instead of putting it into another array? the code i provided above is definetly working (added fiddle to the answer)

Answer (score 0):

yes i totally get you but my problem is peculiar . i am getting this json data from a html table

```
$('#convert-table').click( function() {
var table = $('#example-table').tableToJSON();
 console.log(table);
var data=(JSON.stringify(table));
  });
```

.so the data that comes out is 
**[{"Month":"jan", "Hits":"235", "user":"17"}, {"Month":"feb", "Hits":"1", "user":"1"}]**

Comment: are you reloading your view after updating the model? can you provide some fiddle?